# Is there a way to run shell script one liner in prometheus

Tags: shell, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

Is there a way to run shell script one liner in prometheus?.

I am looking to fetch disk space of top level directories under a specific mount & below one liner just does that. Anyway we can run/retrieve result to query in prometheus & in turn show up on Grafana dashboard. `node_filesystem_avail_bytes` & `node_filesystem_size_bytes` seems to supporting only for mount points.

```
du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -h 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: See [Monitoring directory sizes with the (Node Exporter) Textfile Collector](https://www.robustperception.io/monitoring-directory-sizes-with-the-textfile-collector/)